# Where is the server.dat equivalent at 10.1?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

Prior to 10.1, I could locate the **server.dat** file, and programmatically find out the arcgisoutput folder URL location (virtual directory when using IIS)

e.g.

```
<Directory>
 <Path>c:\arcgisserver\arcgisoutput</Path>
 <URL>http://lap-303689/arcgisoutput</URL>
 <Description></Description>
 <Type>output</Type>
 <Cleaning>sliding</Cleaning>
 <MaxFileAge>600</MaxFileAge>
</Directory>
```

At 10.1, the arcgisserver folder default location is now:
*C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput*

This is fine, but **how do I find out what URL was set to in the post install?**

I understand that there is now an embedded Tomcat within 10.1 (similar to Java edition of AGS), but I am unsure on which file contains the URL info (including the port number).

-EDIT-
**Have reopened this Q, as have agreed with FredP that there should be a better approach to get the arcgisserver physical AND virtual paths from ArcObjects.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue a HTTP request through the ArcGIS Server REST Administration API. See [Scripting with the ArcGIS Server Administrator API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005r1000000), which is Python-oriented, but covers the ground quite well).

For example, when I issue a request to ; `http://arcgisserverhostname/arcgis/admin/system/directories/arcgisoutput?f=pjson`, I get

```
{
  "name": "arcgisoutput",
  "physicalPath": "C:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgisoutput",
  "directoryType": "OUTPUT",
  "cleanupMode": "TIME_ELAPSED_SINCE_LAST_MODIFIED",
  "maxFileAge": 10,
  "description": "Stores various information generated by services, such as map images.",
  "virtualPath": "/rest/directories/arcgisoutput"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Prior 10.1, I alsways used the **getVirtualOutputDirectory()** of the MapServer object:
 http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/carto/MapServer.html#getVirtualOutputDirectory()

This methods returned for me (under AGS-Java) the complete output path, like:
  http://myServer/arcgisoutput

Now in 10.1, I just get "/rest/directories/....". It's a relative path ! :-(

I suppose it's a BUG in the 10.1 version, it should return the full virtual outputpath as under AGS-Java-10.

Tom

Answer (score 3):

I write a file called "help.html" here :

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
```

I get it here :

```
http://localhost:6080/help.html
```

Now here is how I would proceed:

1. identify the install directory, 
   hint : it's in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\Server10.1 under a string called "InstallDir"
2. append "framework\runtime\tomcat\webapps\ROOT" to C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\ 
   and you have your PHYSICAL DIRECTORY
3. Now get the local ip or hostname and make sure the port is correct.
   HINT : 
   parse through C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml
   and you will find the PORT.
   Be careful, there are a few PORT's mentioned in there, find the one with

   it MUST be the line with protocol=http/1.1

IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT FOLDER ACCESS :
The folder framework\runtime\tomcat\webapps\ROOT will not be writable by your application.
I suggest you add a sub-folder \temp and change the sharing securities to allow all users to write/read.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we should be able to use IServerDirectory2 .. but when I call this, all the returned values are empty.

```
IServerDirectory2Ptr pServerDir(CLSID_ServerDirectory);
    if (pServerDir)
    {
        BSTR bstrPath(L"");
        BSTR bstrUrl(L"");
        BSTR sDescr(L"");
        hr = pServerDir->get_Description(&sDescr);
        hr = pServerDir->get_Path(&bstrPath);
        hr = pServerDir->get_URL(&bstrUrl);
    }
```

[Link V9.3.1](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriServer/IServerDirectory2.htm) | [Link ArcGIS10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//003z0000005t000000)

Comment: We tried IServerDirectoryPtr=returns empty strings; IServerMachine3Ptr=invalid pointer; IServerObjectAdmin=Unable to create (error=Class not registered)

Answer (score 1):

You also have the method **getPhysicalOutputDirectory()** of the MapServer object: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/carto/MapServer.html#getPhysicalOutputDirectory()

This returns the physical directory of the mapservice.

Comment: do you know if this exists at 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

```
This only works for ArcGIS10.1

// 1. get HKLM\software\esri\server10.1\ "installDir"
// 2. you get something like C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\
// 3. add \framework\etc\machine-config.xml
// 4. you open that file and look for <HTTP>6080</HTTP>
// 5. you can also read the <MachineName> tag
// 6. open the file c:\arcgisserver\config-store\serverdirs\arcgisoutput.json
// 7. it's json code : get the physicalPath (ex: C:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgisoutput)
// 7.1 : TEST write some "foo.html" in there
// 8.                : get the maxFileAge
// 9.                : get the cleanUpMode 
// 10.               : get the "virtualpath" (ex: /rest/directories/arcgisoutput)
// 11. use the machine name and port you got in (4) and (5) and add the virtualpath you got in (10)
// 12. You should have a URL like : http://servername:6080/rest/directories/arcgisoutput
// 12.1 : TEST with a browser http://servername:6080/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/foo.html and it should work. 

in my case : 

I write: C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput\foo.html
and I get it also from: http://twirl:6080/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/foo.html

F
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question, thus this answer late - but you should be using the REST Admin to get this sort of information. You build up URLs, and using a token obtained through the generateToken you supply credentials and then use them to query certain aspects of the server.

See this help link for information regarding the Server Admin API:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/

The directory information (from the original question) is available at:
http://:6080/arcgis/admin/system/directories

If you want Python code that demonstrates how to get a token and some queries (not this one specifically, but again, just build up the URL), check here:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=12dde73e0e784e47818162b4d41ee340